# Why does Spring boot war file works in localhost only with artifactId but not in AWS Elastic BeanStalk?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am developing a Spring boot war application in my local. 
I'm using same tomcat 8 version in my local and in production (AWS BeanStalk - the default Java 8 Tomcat 8 version).

The URL for web app is http://localhost:8080/artifactId in my local, but in production, just my domain name www.example.com runs the webapp.
This causes certain pieces not working fine in production, all pieces work fine in local. If I remove the artifact Id in annotations and other places in the webapp, things partially work in local and all other pieces work fine in production.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you need your context to be `www.example.com/artifactId` then try the following:

In your `application.properties` (should be on `src\main\resources`) add this:

```
server.contextPath=/artifactId
server.servlet.contextPath=/artifactId
```

If that doesn't work for you, this [thread may have what you need](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=229121&#229121)